# subprocess.popen leaves out ghost sessions

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess

I want to launch multiple cmd and python files at the same time and not wait for response.

With the above solution, `subprocess.popen` leaves out ghost session in Task Manager (Windows).

**test.py**

```
import time
time.sleep(5)  # each subprocess lasts long enough to have 10 sessions active
```

**test.cmd**

```
call <anaconda_dir>/Scripts/activate.bat
python C:\Users\abc\Desktop\test.py
```

**parent.py**

```
import subprocess

p1 = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\test.cmd"
p2 = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\test.py"

for i in range(10):
    print(i)

    if i % 2 == 0:
        subprocess.Popen(p1, shell=True)
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(p2, shell=True)
```

Comment: You can't just throw away the `Popen()` objects - you have to keep a reference to them (in a list, perhaps), and periodically call `.poll()` on them.  Only when that returns a non-None value can you discard the object.

Comment: I have understood that `popen` is to be used when one is not interested in outcome of subprocess.

Comment: does `subprocess.Popen(p1, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)` fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For one, you do probably want to hang on to the `Popen` objects and eventually wait for them to quit.
- Second, you don't need a batch file to use an Anaconda environment's interpreter; just use the `python.exe` within that `Scripts` (or `bin`) directory; similarly, use `sys.executable` to refer to the current Python interpreter's executable.
- You also don't need `shell=True`.

```
import subprocess
import sys

anaconda_python = "anaconda_dir/Scripts/python.exe"  # TODO: correct this path

script = "C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\test.py"

processes = []

for i in range(10):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        command = [sys.executable, script]  # current interpreter
    else:
        command = [anaconda_python, script]  # another interpreter

    processes.append(subprocess.Popen(command))

for proc in processes:
    proc.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Why do you use `proc.wait()`? It seems to work without it as well. In such a case, I suppose it is not necessary to save SubprocessPopen objects in a list either?

Comment: I'd still keep the objects around so they don't get garbage collected...